# How to make dynamic values in pie chart

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here i am using pie chart and i given static values means it is working fine , but instead of static i want give dynamic value it is not working

1. ['Trip With Single Occupancy',     2845] instead of this **i have to give ['Trip With Single Occupancy',     40],** *because employeeTraveld 1 means total_Trip is 40* like this i have to give remaining four values

---

> I tried like this but nt hapening

```
            var res=jQuery.parseJSON(result);// convert the json
        console.log(res);


            $.each( res['data'], function( key, value ) { 
                var employeeTraveld = value.employeeTraveld;
                var total_Trip = value.total_Trip;
                console.log(employeeTraveld + " = "+ total_Trip);

                {
                  "status": "success",
                  "data": [
                    {
                      "employeeTraveld": "1",
                      "total_Trip": "40"
                    },
                    {
                      "employeeTraveld": "2",
                      "total_Trip": "19"
                    },
                    {
                      "employeeTraveld": "3",
                      "total_Trip": "26"
                    },
                    {
                      "employeeTraveld": "4",
                      "total_Trip": "21"
                    }
                  ]
                }


                var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                      ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
                      ['Trip With Single Occupancy',     if(employeeTraveld == 1){total_Trip}],
                      ['Trip With Two Occupancy',      if(employeeTraveld == 2){total_Trip}],
                      ['Trip With Three Occupancy',  if(employeeTraveld == 3){total_Trip}],
                      ['Trip With Four Occupancy', if(employeeTraveld == 4){total_Trip}]
                    ]);
            });
```

```js
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {

    var result = {
       "status": "success",
       "data": [
      {
        "employeeTraveld": "1",
        "total_Trip": "40"
      },
      {
        "employeeTraveld": "2",
        "total_Trip": "19"
      },
      {
        "employeeTraveld": "3",
        "total_Trip": "26"
      },
      {
        "employeeTraveld": "4",
        "total_Trip": "21"
      }
       ]
     }
     
     //console.log(result);
   
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
       ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
       ['Trip With Single Occupancy',     2845],
       ['Trip With Two Occupancy',      2717],
       ['Trip With Three Occupancy',  5369],
       ['Trip With Four Occupancy', 1723]
     ]); 
     
     var options = {
      title: 'My Daily Activities'
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));

    chart.draw(data, options);
   
  }
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={'modules':[{'name':'visualization','version':'1.1','packages':['corechart']}]}"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
       <div id="piechart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
```

Comment: The dynamic values would be loaded from an `xhr` call? or how?